# Where two database instance for single database are used for Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle

I was reading recently relationship between instance and database.  Oracle documentation mentions that it is possible to have multiple database instance for single database.  However, single instance can not be associated with two different database.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/startup.htm  ( See fig.  13-2 )

I understood part what they are trying to say.  I would like to know where two database instance of same database are used ?  Does it have any practical applications ?

Please elaborate. Thanks !

Comment: Clustering is apparently a use case: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/rac.112/e16795/admin.htm#RACAD900

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any complications in this. The link in your question has following statement:

```
"A database instance is a set of memory structures that manage database files. A database is a set of physical files on disk created by the CREATE DATABASE statement. The instance manages its associated data and serves the users of the database."
```

It means when you install a database your putting together all the necessary files on the disk. Now a database instance refers to a loading necessary files in main memory so that user can work on it. I can do this multiple times if i have sufficient memory using different ports.

A similar analogy can be, say if you a jar file on your disk. Lets call it `"test.jar"`. Now you can call `java - jar test.jar` multiple times isn't it? So can have multiple instances of your program.